# how to trigger click event on dynamically created element in jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, click, element

```
if($('#term').children().length == 0){
        $("#term").append("<ul id='ulDynamic' class='ulDynamic'></ul>");
        var i;
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
            var liDynamic = "Term "+i;
            var liId = "Term"+i;
            $("#ulDynamic").append("<li id="+liId+ " class='listDynamic'>"+ liDynamic +"</li>");
                    if(i==0){
                       $('#'+liId).click();
        }
    }
```

.click() is not working since liId is a dynamically created element. I want the first li element to be auto clicked when the page loads. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 13):

do something like:

```
$("#term").append("<ul id='ulDynamic' class='ulDynamic'></ul>");
        var i;
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
            var liDynamic = "Term "+i;
            var liId = "Term"+i;
            var $li = $("<li />", {
                "id" : liId,
                "class" : 'listDynamic'
            }).html(liDynamic).click(function() {
                alert("clicked:" + this.id);
            });

            $("#ulDynamic").append($li);            
        }
$("#ulDynamic").find("li:first").trigger("click");
```

Demo :: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VVjk/)

Comment: @user2682527 you could mark it as Accepted Answer if it worked for you..!

Answer (score 8):

I have seen your ID is starting with `Term` so you can use .on() to add click event on DOM that are added later.

**Exapmple**

```
$(document).on('click','[id^="Term"]',function(){
  //code here
});
```

Comment: He wants to trigger the click event, not bind and event to the the click event.

Answer (score 5):

Try with `.trigger()` like

```
 $('#'+liId).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score -4):

use event delgation `on` inside your ready function

try this

```
 $(function(){
   $('#term').on('click','li:first',function(){
    //do your stuff
   });
 });
```

Comment: He wants to trigger the click event, not bind and event to the the click event.