# Grab html element value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can i grab html element value using php or javascript?
I tried using jQuery with DOM ready event, but the problem is that the value that i wanna grab is dynamically loaded from somewhere, and when i use jQuery with DOM ready event most of the times it happens that the DOM is ready but the value of the element is empty (its still not loaded) and when i grab the value with jQuery it gives the empty value of the element, because i am grabbing it before its loaded in the element.

How can i grab the value after its loaded? Is there some kind of trigger or event?

Any help / ideas are appreciated !

The accepted solution works, but i think this is even better :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bool = false;
  jQuery('.element').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
    if(bool == false) {
      alert("DOM NODE INSERTED !");
      bool = true;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: post your code so i can take a look. But what is loading the content dynamically, is it php?

Comment: sounds like a job for : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to trigger click event on dynamically created element in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734393/how-to-trigger-click-event-on-dynamically-created-element-in-jquery)

Comment: Probably not, since he's looking for the value and he's not looking to attach an event to it, so jQuery.on won't help him and the question is definitely not a duplicate

Comment: well i guess we are interpreting the question differently

Comment: Just read the question, he definitely wants the value I think

Comment: Yes i want the value, lets say at the begining i have <span class="some-num">0</span> and after that i have <span class="some-num">1355</span>. How can i grab the value (1355) after its changed? I will try all the posted ideas now.

Comment: We talking about element text then?

Comment: Well i guess yes. I want the value/text/string wrapped inside the html tag with class 'some-num' for example.

Comment: The dynamic content is loaded with javascript/jquery i think. Its a  plugin for wordpress but i think it would be impossible to track where that value comes from.

Comment: try subscribing to a change event on the element, chances are if it's a decent plugin it triggers a change event manually when the value/text gets updated

Comment: Or maybe it adds a class or something else to indicate that the value has been updated

Comment: It does not add class or change the html in any way i checked that now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using window.load as below:

```
  $( window ).load(function() {
     // Run code
  });
```

This will guarantee that the page is fully loaded first

Further to your comment. You can't assign load event to a single element just like that. You need to wait for all elements to be loaded(whole page) if you want to use the window.load event. However, what I could suggest you is something like :

```
   function checkStatus() {
      var check = $(#yourELEMENT NAME)
      if (check == null) {
         //Change the time to whatever you like
         setTimeout("checkStatus()", 100);
     } else {
    ...
   }
  }
```

In this case you will wait some time until the element loads which should be enough for it to be set and then you can manipulate it as you like. And lastly, please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: This actually works, one disadvantage is that it needs the whole page to be loaded, how can i make it to trigger only when my element is loaded/changed not the whole page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
$("#Blaah").load(function(){
//Code
});
```

Of course, you don't have to use an id, you can use any CSS selector, to detect when an element is loaded.

Comment: Do you have jQuery on your webpage?

Comment: Yes i have jQuery, i already tried $(window).load and it works, i tried this also with the class of the element that i want to check if loaded, but it doesn't trigger anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Get contents of local element**

```
$(function() {
    // after doc loads will get innerHTML of #myElement
    var elementContents = $("#myElement").html();
});
```

**Get contents of a file's element**

```
$(function() {
    $("#myDiv").load("ajax/test.html #container");
});
```

Comment: this just uses the DOM ready function that Mr. wazzaaap already tried

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't sound much like PHP, but more like JavaScript.

If the element is loaded (with a value) after the page is rendered, putting the script element at the bottom of the page will often work.

If you are waiting for some change from the user/browser, you need to attach to an event, such as onClick, onChange, onBlur, onMouseover, onKeypress, etc.

If you're talking about something else, but specifically using jQuery, jQuery has it own ready function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: This triggers it before the value is loaded :/ I tried this already.

Comment: You should read the question carefully before answering obvious solutions like ready which Mr. wazaaaap says he tried already

Comment: He asked for ideas ("Any help / ideas are appreciated !") and I gave him _three_.

He also posted absolutely no code, didn't seem to **know** if he meant PHP or JavaScript (they are not the same thing) and the question doesn't provide many details, so **all** of us are taking shots in the dark.  Until we get more information about the nature of the problem, script location, event handlers, and ready() are about the only pointers that I (or anyone else, I think) can give him.