# Trigger a click event with dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery

My content changes with ajax and I want that after 200px of scrolling to trigger a click to an element.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 200){
    $(".element")[0].click();
  }
}
```

But this does not work with changing content. On first load it works. But as soon as ajax does it's stuff the event isn't firing anymore. Any ideas? I know about the on event but cannot figure it out how to use it here.

**Update**

The linked question does not help me:

```
$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});
```

this works for clicks or other events. But I don't want to attach a click event, I want to trigger a click event. How could I do it? The change is in an ajax call beyond my control so I cannot add a callback.

Thanks

Comment: So does it work when the element *isn't* dynamically loaded? Perhaps an example would be helpful..

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what specifically doesn't work about it - ie it doesn't click, the correct element isn't clicked, the event of the clicked element isn't fired... etc

Comment: how do your change your content and where is the content loaded? body? some examples help.

Comment: @JoshCrozier  yes, it is working when the element isn't dynamically loaded. yes, nothing is clicked when the element is reloaded. the change is in an ajax call beyond my control so I cannot add a callback.

Comment: @isherwood can you please post an answer how to use on() and trigger a click, not attach a click event like that question wants. I'm unsure how to do it.

Comment: `$('body .element').click()` Should work, replace with your `$('.element;)[0].click();`

Comment: I created a basic example, and it seems to work here for dynamically generated elements - http://jsfiddle.net/frm3vb60/

Comment: Sorry, my suggested duplicate was incorrect. Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734393/how-to-trigger-click-event-on-dynamically-created-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18734655/1264804), you use the `find()` method to look at a static ancestor element's descendant elements:

```
$('#someStaticAncestorElement').find('.element')[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to play with item/object's that aren't there on the very first load JavaScript gets a bit confusing.

jQuery/JS language in simple terms only really can apply to the objects on page load.

The easiest way around this is to delegte functions to a HTML element that is always there on pageload. Most people usually use the `<body>`.

Eg:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 200){
    $( "body" ).delegate( $(".element")[0], "click", function() {
      // Your Code Here
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP isn't trying to add a click event listener, they are trying to *trigger* a click event.